# How to find my TeamViewer ID on SSH?

Tags: ssh, teamviewer

When I tried to run the command `teamviewer --info` I am getting the following output

```
root@vps [~]# /opt/teamviewer8/tv_bin/TeamViewer --info

 TeamViewer                      8.0.20931 

 teamviewerd status              teamviewerd start/running, process 9584 

TeamViewer ID: not found
Try restarting the TeamViewer daemon (e.g. teamviewer --daemon restart)
```

but I can't find my TeamViewer ID. Is there any other in Configuration settings where I can find my TeamViewer ID?

Answer (score 26):

Set your password first:

```
teamviewer --passwd newPassword
```

And the run

```
teamviewer -info
```

It will show you the TeamViewer ID

Comment: I just want to emphasize that you SHOULD set the password first. Although it will not show the ID.

Comment: Not working on TeamViewer server running on Windows (the original question does not set specific operating system, just a example of Linux/Unix shell).

Answer (score 7):

You can inspect the logs :

```
grep -o "id=[0-9]*" /var/log/teamviewer/TeamViewer8_Logfile.log
```

Comment: Command returns nothing

Comment: might be your logs compressed, better is search recursively using `grep -Ro "id=[0-9]*" /var/log/`

Comment: I got snookered initially because I am using TeamViewer 9, so different log path, but its similar enough

Comment: Or have a look at `/var/log/teamviewer/config/global.conf`

Answer (score 4):

You can use :

```
teamviewer --info print version, status, id
```

Comment: This works perfectly in TV 10. There are, though, some cases when it doesn't (i.e. if you manually restart the service)

Comment: how to get the password as well?

Comment: @mcExchange You cannot get existing password but can set new password using :

    sudo teamviewer passwd **[NEW_PASSWORD]**

Answer (score 2):

**Windows** (the original question does not set specific operating system, just a example of Linux/Unix shell) solution:

```
cd %PROGRAMFILES%\TeamViewer\Version7
type TeamViewer7_Logfile.log | more
```

The ID is reported on the **head** lines.
Tested working on v7.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux you can find this in /etc/teamviewer/global.conf. After a couple HUGE lines of gibberish text (certificate keys) you get to ClientIC and ClientID.

Answer (score 0):

The other way is:

```
nano /etc/teamviewer/global.conf
```

You could find the ID from the line:

```
[int32] ClientID = xxxxxxxxxx
```

Also you could access from your local computer, just make sure you have the lines below:

```
[int32] EulaAccepted = 1

[int32] General_DirectLAN = 1
```

On the control side you just use 192.168.1.xxx(the host local IP or hostname) instead of TeamViewer partner ID

You can update your password through command line:

```
teamviewer passwd YrNewPassword
```

If you could do a port forwarding on your gateway/router, to port 5938, you could use domain name or WAN IP address instead of the TeamViewer partner ID and control it from anywhere